# settings.gradle error for react native app

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Here is my `settings.gradle` file

```
rootProject.name = 'myappname'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
```

when running `./gradlew clean` or `./gradlew bundleRelease` im getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/username/Desktop/myappname/android/settings.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'myappname'.
> String index out of range: 0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It is just telling that build failed with an exception. What that exception is? May be run  ./gradlew bundleRelease --info or --debug option to get more information about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your expo version in `package.json` is set as:

```
"expo": "^43.0.1",
```